# Is APRS the tracking protocol for the BTech GMRS PRO or the Vero 75 Ham version

Tags: digital-modes, baofeng, aprs

Looking for confirmation if the Btech GMRS Pro and the Vero 75 are using APRS as the tracking protocol for their radio's. We're working on an EmComm/ EOC integration project and were looking to see what is already broken out.
Kind regards
Jonathan

Comment: do you have them at hand? A [32$ RTL dongle](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0129EBDS2/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=rsv0f-20&linkId=9806dfa291f74f7cdb49e2cfbe3d34eb) would allow you to rather trivially record the emissions and look for APRS in that.

Comment: (Note that *I* wouldn't use APRS for anything but compatibility with existing APRS, which really is a ham thing in practice. Doesn't mean someone else wouldn't – just means that if you're in the position to design things from scratch, you'd make use of ~ 40 years of technical progress and also use something that is easier to implement on the hardware you have already)

Comment: Marcus.... Thanks... I enjoyed your quote on two days in the lab saving you an hour read... My preliminary scan suggested that the BTECH GMRS Pro radio's we're looking at as part of an island Emcomm project, were derived from a China Ham clone (Vero N75) that used APRS protocols... BTECH has decent Bluetooth Android/ IOS rig control/ GPS/ texting app, but we want to break out it out so we can fine tune it for our purposes.. Don't have the radio's yet but shortly... Appreciate your link for an RTL dongle... My old Hack One gave up the ghost on me and I've never replaced it... Kind regards...Jon